# Running sonarqube in jenkinsfile's containertemplate

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to build sonarqube with ContainerTemplate - I'm using [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/newtmitch/sonar-scanner/) image (newtmitch/sonar-scanner).

When I run `docker run -ti -v $(pwd):/usr/src newtmitch/sonar-scanner` it connects to my localhost sonar (defined in sonar-project.properties), and I get logs of sonar tests.

But when I use podtemplate instead, it doesn't give me any output (only "running"). Why the container template doesn't run sonar scanner? This is the relevant part of my code:

```
podTemplate(label: 'jenkins-pipeline', containers: [
    containerTemplate(name: 'jnlp', image: 'jenkinsci/jnlp-slave:2.62', args: '${computer.jnlpmac} ${computer.name}', workingDir: '/home/jenkins', resourceRequestCpu: '500m', resourceLimitCpu: '500m', resourceRequestMemory: '1024Mi', resourceLimitMemory: '1024Mi'),
    containerTemplate(name: 'docker', image: 'docker:1.12.6', command: 'cat', ttyEnabled: true),
    containerTemplate(name: 'maven', image: 'maven:3.5.0-jdk-8', command: 'cat', ttyEnabled: true),
    containerTemplate(name: 'sonar-scanner-newtmitch', image: 'newtmitch/sonar-scanner', command: 'cat', ttyEnabled: true),
    containerTemplate(name: 'kubectl', image: 'lachlanevenson/k8s-kubectl:v1.8.3', command: 'cat', ttyEnabled: true)
],
volumes:[
    hostPathVolume(mountPath: '/var/run/docker.sock', hostPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'),
]){

  node ('jenkins-pipeline') {
     container("maven"){
       checkout scm
     }
     container("sonar-scanner-newtmitch"){
       stage("run sonar scanner"){
         sh "echo running"
       }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved this issue, but forgot the question is open. I saw that the container template override the ENTRYPOINT of sonar-image. so I had to add stage:

```
stage("scan"){
  sh "sonar-scanner"
}
```